# AngularJS Response does not match configured parameter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I've got a problem with service configuration. I want to display one user by this function:

```
$scope.findOne = function() {
    $scope.user = Users.get({
        userId: $stateParams.userId
    });
};
```

But I am in trouble with User service :( I don't know, how should I change my the code to avoid angular error:

> Error in resource configuration for action `object`. Expected response
>   to contain an array but got an {2}

Here is a code of my actual working service (without function findOne working of course:))

```
'use strict';

angular.module('users').factory('Users', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('users', {}, { 
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            },
            remove: {
                method: 'DELETE',
                url: 'users/:id',
                params: {id: '@_id'}
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, I'd say your `users` API endpoint is expecting `/users/:userId` for GET requests. Your code at the moment will request `/users?userId=nnn`. You need to add an action for `get` with the ID in the URL, eg

```
return $resource('users', {id: '@userId'}, {
    get: {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'users/:id',
        isArray: false
    },
    // etc
```

You can also make `users/:id` the default URL as long as it doesn't interfere with your other action configurations.

Comment: Hmm, you shouldn't have to but maybe add `isArray: false` (see my updated answer). Can you check the request and response in your browser's *Network* console?

Comment: `isArray: false` I've tried yesterday too, but without result :( Response is really array of one entry on zero position: `[{_id: "5526e4fb6276b5c01c8ca76d", displayName: "Test Netest",…}]`. Request URL: `http://localhost:3000/users?userId=5526e4fb6276b5c01c8ca76d `

Comment: If I add `console.log($scope.user)` to my findOne function, it will write to console this: `Resource {$promise: Object, $resolved: false, $get: function, $save: function, $query: function…}`